# Python 2.6 Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex

I am having a hard time figuring out why this code does not produce a match object. I am running python version 2.6.6 on Centos operating system.

```
>>> x = r'\[GOOD\]'
>>> y = r'it made me feel \[GOOD\]'
>>> match = re.search(x, y)
>>> print match
None
```

My expected output would be a match object like:

```
>>> match = re.search ('hi', 'hilllaos')
>>> print match
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x3299ac0>
```

Any explanations?

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> x = r'\\\[GOOD\\\]'
>>> y = r'it made me feel \[GOOD\]'
>>> re.search(x, y)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x8aa3d40>
```

`\\\[` first `\` escapes the  second(middle) slash and the last slash escapes the `[`.

Using just `\[` in the regex you're escaping just the `[` i.e the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), so it'll not match the actual `\` in the string `y`.

Comment: So you can use multiple escapes for further escaping?

Answer (score 2):

You weren't looking for the slashes:

```
>>> re.search(r'\[GOOD\]', 'it made me feel [GOOD]')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000026C5C60>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = r'\[GOOD\]'
print(len(x))  # prints 8
print(x[0])  # prints a backslash
```

The string has backslashes in it.

The pattern, however, does not match the backslashes.  In a regular expression, a backslash modifies what follows it; in this example, the backslash disables the special features of `[`.

So your regular expression just matches the literal string `[GOOD]`.  But your `x` does not contain that string because of the backslashes.

If you want your target string to simply contain `[GOOD]` then remove the backslashes:

```
y = r'it made me feel [GOOD]'
```

If you want the search string to match backslashes in the target string, you must modify your pattern.  This would work:

```
x = r'..GOOD..'  # use dot to match anything
```

But to actually match exactly a backslash in a regular expression, you use a double backslash.  The backslash is a special character that modifies the character that follows it, so to get a backslash you double it:

```
x = r'\\.GOOD.\\'  match actual backslashes; use dot to match square braces
```

So you use `\\` to match a backslash and `\[` for a left square brace and `\]` for a right square brace.  Put it all together:

```
x = r'\\\[GOOD\]\\'
```

But you aren't using any of the special features of regular expressions here.  This is just a regular expression that matches one literal string.

By the way, Python's feature of "raw strings" is handy here.  In a normal string you need to double a backslash to get a single backslash, just as in a pattern you need to double a backslash to match a backslash.  Thus to use a normal string to write a pattern you need to double the backslash twice:

```
x = '\\\\\\[GOOD\\]\\\\'  # note not a raw string
```

Yuck!

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression compiler interprets backslashes too, so your pattern (`x`) *effectively* becomes `{GOOD]`.  And that doesn't appear in your string, so no match.  If you want to match strings with a backslash followed by `{GOOD` followed by backslash followed by `]`, then you need to double the backslashes in the pattern *and* escape the special characters too:

```
x = r'\\\[GOOD\\\]'
```

Now that pattern will match `y`.